# How to copy fields from one object to another including collections

Tags: java

I have two objects(json for simplicity). Fields with null value is omitted.

```json
//target object
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "set":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "a": "a"
        }
    ]
}
//patch object
{
    "a": "new value",
    "set":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "a": "new value"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "a": "new value"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I implement a patching function so the result looks like this:

```json
{
    "a": "new value",
    "b": "b",
    "set":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "a": "new value"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "a": "new value"
        }
    ]
}
```

The value presented in the patch object will replace the value in the original object.

And for arrays/sets if an object with the same id exists, do the same merging process for all the child object fields.
If not just copies the child over.

How can I achieve this function without doing something like `if(patch.getField!=null) target.setField(patch.getField())`
I know reflection could be one solution but I just can't come up with something that looks better than the if spaghetti.

Comment: Fundamentally, you can't avoid a conditional statement that only copies a field if it's present in the patch, because that's **how it needs to work**.  But a couple of observations: if this is supposed to be general, then copying is inherently recursive, with subcases for (in json terms) primitives, arrays, objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class Foo {
    String a, b;
    Map<Integer, String> set = new HashMap<>();

    public Foo(String a, String b, Map<Integer, String> set) {
        this.a = a; this.b = b;
        this.set.putAll(set);
    }

    public void patch(Foo patch) {
        a = Optional.ofNullable(patch.a).orElse(a);
        b = Optional.ofNullable(patch.b).orElse(b);
        set.putAll(patch.set);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo[a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", set=" + set + "]";
    }
}
```

And

```
Foo target = new Foo("a", "b", Map.of(1, "a"));
Foo patch = new Foo("new value", null, Map.of(1, "new value", 2, "new value"));
target.patch(patch);
System.out.println(target);
```

output:

```
Foo[a=new value, b=b, set={1=new value, 2=new value}]
```